# Check if a string contains a specific string using array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to c#. I would like to know if a string such as a user name contains a specific word. I want to get those specific words from an array.Here's a example.`

```
Console.Write("Name: ");
_name = Console.ReadLine();
name = Program.ProperNameMethod( _name);
Console.WriteLine();

string[] badWordArray = { "aBadword1", "aBadWord2", "aBadWord3" };

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) // Would like to check for the badwordarray aswell)
```

(Update)

Thank you all but me learning c# only for about a month could not cover lambda or regex yet. I will have a look at these codes while later.

Comment: what is `ProperNameMethod`

Comment: @Reza Taibur please mark my answer as accepted if it helps you.

Comment: I made a method that would convert the first word of the string to a Block letter.@un-lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want *case insensitive* validation:

```
string[] badWordArray = { "aBadword1", "aBadWord2", "aBadWord3" };

Boolean isBadWord = badWordArray
  .Any(badWord => name.IndexOf(badword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Or if you verify on *current culture*

```
Boolean isBadWord = badWordArray
  .Any(badWord => name.IndexOf(badWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

*Paranoic* case involves using *regular expressions* like this:

```
   string[] badWordArray = { "aBadword1", "aBadWord2", "aBadWord3" };

   // Nasty user wants to be rude but pass typical filters...
   String name = "A- Bad..WORD..1 !!!";

   String line = Regex.Replace(name, @"\W", "");

   Boolean isBadWord = badWordArray
     .Any(badWord => line.IndexOf(badWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: I liked your "paranoic case" answer sir. But using contains is more efficient then to use regex.

Comment: @Lost_In_Library: it depends on what you want to achieve. In case of efficiency (huge array of bad words) and lax control you're quite right. But if you want to eliminate just a possibility of being rude, a shadow of a bad word, you have to use regular expressions and the like.

Answer (score 4):

Use following lambda expression to find if name contains the bad words.

```
 bool nameHasBadWords = badWordArray.Any(p => name.Contains(p));
```

Comment: what is that  "p"? @Mahesh Chand?

Comment: p is an alias used to represent individual element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I could to do;

```
        // Lowered bad words array
        string[] badWordArray = { "abadword1", "abadword2", "abadword3" };

        bool isBadWord = false;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            name = name.ToLower();
            isBadWord = badWordArray.Any(badWord => name.Contains(badWord));
        }
```

I also tested other answers too;

**459 ms**:

```
.Any(badWord => string.Equals(name, badWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

**1464 ms**:

```
.Any(badWord => name.IndexOf(badWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

**247 ms**:

```
.Any(badWord => name.Contains(badWord));
```

Here is my simple (*&stupid*) test code:

```
        var name = "tuckyou";

        // Lowered bad words array
        string[] badWordArray = { "abadword1", "abadword2", "abadword3" };

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        int oneMillion = 1000000;

        bool isBadWord = false;

        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < oneMillion; i++)
        {
            isBadWord = badWordArray.Any(badWord => string.Equals(name, badWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        stopwatch.Reset();

        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < oneMillion; i++)
        {
            isBadWord = badWordArray.Any(badWord => name.IndexOf(badWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        stopwatch.Reset();

        stopwatch.Start();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            name = name.ToLower();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < oneMillion; i++)
        {
            isBadWord = badWordArray.Any(badWord => name.Contains(badWord));
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Ofcourse, using stopWatch is not accurate. But it's giving an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you said you are a beginner. Here is a easier way. I know those answers are better than this but this should be good for beginners.

```
            Console.Write("Name: ");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            //The words that you dont want your user to have
            string[] array = new string[2];
            array[0] = "bad";
            array[1] = "reallybad";

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {

                //Used to lower so user cant get away with stuffs like: rEALLyBAd
                if (userInput.Contains(array[i].ToLower()))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid name!");

                }

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```